# How to automate print functionality using TCP/IP Printer Port?

Tags: java, tcp, automation

TCP/IP Printer Port can we automate and verify the printer functionality. Does anyone have an idea of it? if not any alternative mechanism to automate printer functionality using open source automation tools?

Comment: What functionality do you want to automate? Also, what printer and what TCP port are you talking about, not all printers are the same?

Comment: I want to simulate printer functionality in my automation code. simply after a click on the printer button, I want to print the same content in my code. Thank you for checking the solution, Joni, do you need more details please let me know.

Comment: Yes we need a lot more details. Are you creating a software simulator for a printer? Or trying to automate manual tasks done with an existing hardware printer?

Comment: Joni, I'm planning to create a software simulator for a printer. Using that verify the content.

Comment: What exactly do you need the printer simulator to do?

Comment: In our application, we have inventory details listed in the application, when we click on the printer we getting the printout. In my simulation keep  TCP port open and listening to the application and then click on the printer button, take the data which is sent to the printer, and print in the automation code. (Using TCP Layer), that is my plan.

Comment: So you don't actually want to create a printer simulation, or automate an existing physical printer. You want to implement the TCP/IP protocol of a printer in your own software, so that it can be installed as a "printer" in the machine where your application runs. Is that correct?

Comment: Joni, other than my solution, do you any suggestions to try out the printer automation?

Comment: This sounds like a lot of work. What is the end goal? Maybe there's an easy way to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Joni, can you give me a suggestion to proceed.

Comment: Can you confirm if I understood you correctly: that you want to create a software implementation of a networked printer, that you can add as a printer to any computer that is connected to the network? If so, I have two followup questions: 1) What is this for? This is a major undertaking and there may be easier ways to achieve your goals. 2) Will you need to simulate also things like amount of ink left, amount of paper left, error notifications like "out of paper" or "out of ink" or "paper jam" etc

Comment: Joni, you misunderstand it. I'm planning to implement a simulator for automation testing. if we used a real printer I need to test the application manually. to avoid manual testing using a simulator plan verify the application printer functionality.

Comment: So we are talking about automating tests of your application, and that when you say "printer button" you don't mean a button on the printer, you mean that there is a "print" button on your application? And you want to simulate pushing that button, having the application open the "choose printer" dialog and you want to verify that the application printed what it was supposed to print. Is that correct? In that case, how is printing implemented in the application? Is the application written in Java? What operating system does it run on? Does the "Print to PDF" option exist, and can you use it?

Comment: joni, yes, in here I'm referring the print button in the application. In my automation, I just want to verify the printer output content. application is written by java. Linux operating system it's working. Print to PDF option not available in the application. if you need more details please let me know.